# SSL-Your connection isn't private with CNAME

Tags: ssl, cname-record

need your help and advise.
I have a site https://mysaaswebsite.com and have enabled CNAME for my customers on cname.mysaaswebsite.com

my customers add booking.customer.com cname to cname.mysaaswebsite.com, it works fine but they get privacy concern error,

This server couldn't prove that it's cname.mysaaswebsite.com; its security certificate is from mysaaswebsite.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Like this there are many customers who are using our service with CNAME.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You will need to automate provisioning and configuring new SSL certificates for each customer domain/subdomain they point at your CNAME.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an SSL certificate work on CNAME'd urls?](https://serverfault.com/questions/228242/does-an-ssl-certificate-work-on-cnamed-urls)

Comment: Thanks, but can you let us know more on how to achieve it. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have certificate for `domain` it will not work for `host.domain`. You need to add (when create certificate request) Subject Alt Name(s) or request wildcard certificate which will work for `host1.domain`, `host2.domain`, etc if it is issued with Subject Name for `*.domain` (but again will not work for `domain`)

Comment: Thanks. I did add a wild card certificate. still it did not work.
my primary domain is imeetify.com and customer's URL request is cal.digitallysaint.com , and we are getting same error even after adding wild card certificate

Comment: is there any restriction on using CPanel Auto SSL ? should we move to other SSL providers?

Comment: @BalaG, you should add both domains in certificate, wildcard will not work. Also questions about panels are offtopic here.

Comment: Thanks @romeo for your response. Will check that out.